# How to define a functional by the way it acts on its own output

Tags: functional

I want to define a functional `E` by using the property `E[ E[f[x]] ] := E[f[x]]` for some arbitrary function f[x]. Meaning, that I want Mathematica to evaluate every expression E[ E[f[x]] ] to E[f[x]] for all functions f[x]. How do I make this in Mathematica? I tried

```
E[ E[f_[x]] ] := E[f[x]]
```

but this gives the following error "$IterationLimit::itlim: Iteration limit of 4096 exceeded." and as output Hold[E[f[x]]]. Thanks!

Comment: Hello. First, do not use the letter `E` because it has built-in meaning, type `?E` to see this. So let me use `e` instead (you can replace this by any other name that does not correspond to a symbol with built-in meaning).  Then perhaps what you want is `e[e[expr_]]:=e[expr]`. Try typing `e[e[f[x]]]` now. You can also use something like `Format[e]=Style["E",Blue]` to change the way your `e` is printed in the notebook output.

Comment: Please edit your question so that ALL code is formatted properly. I changed some of it so that you can see how it works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The evaluation loop for `f[f[x]]`will first evaluate `f[x]`and then feed to output to `f` . Therefroe you must prevent the first evaluation. You can do this by giving `f` the attribute `HoldFirst`. Only then you may define `f[f[x]]`:

```
ClearAll[f]
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst]
f[f[x_]] = f[x];
f[x_] = x^2;
f[f[3]]

(* 9 *)
```